# example of a sequence that converges to $0$ but for all real $p\geq1$; $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^p$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I've been trying to give an example of a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=0$ but for all real $p\geq1$; $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^p$ diverges.

I cannot find a simple example; I've tried couple of sequences that converge to $0$ but they either don't work or it is hard to tell if they do work or not!

Also I'm wondering if that "$0$" makes a difference here; can we generally find such example that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=a$ for some real $a$?

Comment: How about $x_n =1/\log n$?

Comment: If you start at $n=1$, then use $1/\log(n+1)$.

Comment: @Gary Yes! That works. Thank you! I would still appreciate other examples and discussion about whether or not $0$ makes a difference.

Comment: If the limit is a non-zero $a$ then $|x_n|^p$ does not tend to zero, i.e., thes series cannot converge.